# Entity Framework sem chave primária

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Toda vez que atualizo o model diagram do meu projeto, perde a referência de qual campo é chave primária, mesmo tento a PK na tabela no meu Banco. Alguém tem ideia do que pode estar ocasionando isso ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você está usando EDMX?

Comment: Isso mesmo cara

Comment: Você pode tirar uma foto do seu diagrama mostrando algumas das entidades que estão perdendo a chave primária?

Comment: Coloquei as imagens... Se você notar no meu diagrama tem o UsuarioCodigo como chave, mas no meu codebehind nao ta como chave, ai toda vez tenho que colocar ele como key

Comment: Conheço pouco o que o EDMX faz sozinho, mas meu palpite é a nomenclatura que está fora do padrão dele. O correto seria `UsuarioId`, e não `UsuárioCodigo`. Minha sugestão, na verdade, seria abandonar o EDMX e usar os Models somente texto, menos propensos a erros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já montei alguns projetos neste cenário mas nunca tive problemas neste sentido. Porém quando modelo bancos, eu sempre coloco a PK também como coluna identidade. Que versão do entity você está usando? veja um bug parecido neste link:

http://dotnetwindow.blogspot.com.br/2012/06/using-decimal-as-primary-key-in-entity.html